# Struct stat and stat function failure

Tags: c, struct, stat, scandir

So, I'm trying to make a sort of ls function. Here's my code to the description of each file

```
struct stat fileStat;
struct dirent **files;

num_entries = scandir(filename, &files, file_select, alphasort);
stat(files[i-1]->d_name,fileStat);
```

for some reasons once it gets to stat it returns a -1. I was thinking it was because fileStat is not big enough to store the values, but I'm not sure how to solve that. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Use `errno` to determine why function fails.

Comment: ok it says no suchfile or directory ... I was able to fix it by just having a if loop that does nothing when it returns error. but yeah... how do I properly deal with this?

Comment: What is the value of `i`? See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: I use i to run through the files in a for loop until position num_entries.

Comment: The scandir filenames are **not** *paths*. Perhaps you need to prepend the "`filename`" there.

Comment: And naturally, this is **not** a self-contained example.

Comment: yeah, actually I'm trying this right now
if(stat(files[i-1]->d_name,&fileStat) == 0){
}
however, for some reason I can't print anything inside...

Comment: @JoseA people are asking for a [mcve] that _you_ need to provide by editing your question. Describing your code and posting bits of code in comments is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider yourself to look at [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). In short stat() returns:

> On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is
>   set appropriately.

And the errno's list is:

- EACCES
- EBADF
- EFAULT
- ELOOP
- ENAMETOOLONG
- ENOENT
- ENOMEM
- ENOTDIR
- EOVERFLOW

After calling stat, check it's return value with and if it equals -1, check errno (with switch).

Example:

```
if(stat(files[i-1]->d_name,fileStat)) {
   switch(errno) {
   case EACCES:
       // Add code or at least 
       perror("STAT ERROR:");
       break;

   case EBADF:
       // ...
       break;

   case EFAULT:
       // ...
       break;

       // ...
       // Do this to all possible errno's for the stat
       // ...
   case EOVERFLOW:
       // ...
       break;
   }
}
```

If you have troubles with storing path, try to declare array as this (if you using linux):

```
#include <linux/limits.h>
//...
char current_path[PATH_MAX];
```

If you using Windows:

```
#include <windows.h>
//...
char current_path[MAX_PATH];
```

P.S. Thanks for [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) for pointing out my switch typo :)

Comment: You can't have `case EFAULT:` twice in a single `switch` :)